# How to call controller scope function from directive

Tags: angularjs

below is directive declaration in html page

```
<navigation menu="MenuList"></navigation>
```

in above declaration MenuList contain datasoruce from server.

below is my template for menu

```
<ul id="accordion" class="sm sm-vertical sm-blue sid_button">
    <li style="padding: 4px 3px 6px 4px;" ng-repeat="item in menu">
        <a class="has-submenu" href="#" id="">
            <span class="field_work_icon"></span>
            <div class="li_title pr_title" style="line-height: 37px;">{{item.varDisplayName}}</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </a>
        <ul class="left4 ulwidth211">
            <li ng-repeat="item1 in item.submenu">
                <a href="#" ng-click="MenuClick('{{item1.varDashboardID}}','{{item1.varDisplayName}}')\">{{item1.varDisplayName}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

in above template i have attached MenuClick event to anchor tag. which is definde in my controller. but when i clicked on menu it is not called

i have follwing directive in my angular app.

this directive create dynamic menu.

```
app.directive("navigation", ['$compile', '$rootScope', function ($compile,  $rootScope) {
       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           replace: true,
           scope: {
               menu: '='
           },
           templateUrl: "template.html",
           compile: function (el) {
               var contents = el.contents().remove();
               return function (scope, el) {
                   $compile(contents)(scope, function (clone) {
                       el.append(clone);
                   });
               };
           }
       };
   }])
```

with help of this directive my menu is created as it should.

but one thing not working is click function

below is my controller function which not called

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'Applicationservice', 'WebApiBaseUri', 'ngDialog', '$rootScope', '$sce', '$timeout', 'AppURL', 'AuthenticationService', function ($scope, Applicationservice, WebApiBaseUri, ngDialog, $rootScope, $sce, $timeout, AppURL, AuthenticationService) {
$scope.MenuClick = function (dashBoardID, baseUrl) {
        if (dashBoardID != "") {
            window.location.href = Applicationservice.BaseURL() + "/Menu/Report/";
            sessionStorage.setItem("DashboardID", dashBoardID);
        } else {
            window.location.href = Applicationservice.BaseURL() + "/Menu/" + baseUrl + "/";
        }
}]);
```

Comment: have you checked console?

Comment: @JigarPrajapati yes i have checked my console. there is no error.

Comment: There is a typo : you don't need to do braces near : 
 <a href="#" ng-click="MenuClick('{{item1.varDashboardID}}','{{item1.varDisplayName}}')\">{{item1.varDisplayName}}</a>

Just remove braces around your variable.

Comment: It should be like : MenuClick('item1.varDashboardID','item1.varD‌​isplayName')\

Comment: when i have removed braces its showing element in dev tool like below ng-click="MenuClick('item1.varDashboardID','item1.varDisplayName')" which wrong and when i keep braces it shows ng-click="MenuClick('92C325B3-59BA-EF2A-A836-5883495CFA0D','Distribution')" which right

Comment: actually i haven't tested your code, but as per the standards ng-click is a angular's built in directives so by braces you don't need to tell angular, the code you are writing is of Aguilar's, that's why i have said that.

Comment: @JigarPrajapati thank you very much as you said braces are not required this solved my problem

Comment: Then you should up vote my comment or answer :)

Comment: i have already upvoted your comment

Answer (score 0):

You should use `bindToController` property into your directive instead of isolated scope, then you can call controller functions having a referenced scope between controller and directive.

**edit:**

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nvdf83ox/ 
There we have two controllers:

- `HomeController` which has scope inside all html view of your home page. You have access to his functions via `vmHome` scope name.
- `NavigationController` which has scope inside our directive view and it's called as `vmNav` to access scope.

Use `bindToController` with Angular > 1.3

Comment: can you please give some example or reference where i can find how to do that ? thanks

Comment: check out this todd motto tutorial about it: https://toddmotto.com/no-scope-soup-bind-to-controller-angularjs/#solution , if you can attach a fiddle i could help you more.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
```

> This is how you do it in Angular 1.3
>   In Directive, use controllerAs syntax, set bindToController: true.  When set, the component’s properties are bound to the controller rather than to the scope.  Refer: 
>   http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html.

Also the Todd's angular styleguide mentioned in another answer.

```
        app.directive('hello', function(){
          return {
            controller: 'HelloCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            bindToController: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
               name: '='  
            },
            template: '<div><a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.sayHello()">{{ctrl.name}}</a></div>',
          };
        })

        app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.name = 'World';
        });
```

> There is no $scope here.  The directive uses values name and calls sayHello using vm (this)

```
        app.controller('HelloCtrl', function(){

            var vm = this;
            vm.name = 'hello world123';
            vm.sayHello = function(){
              console.log('hello world !!!');
            }
        });
```

> This gets even better with Angular 1.4 again check the links above.
>
> Link to working plnkr
>   http://plnkr.co/edit/hdOrtfYrt83U5kxbpUFi?p=preview